# how to set label and size of igrah network from&to nodes separately

Tags: r, igraph

I'm new to the R package `{igraph}`, I want to create a user_id-state network, as there are much more users than states, I want to remove the label of user_id but keep the state ones. Meanwhile, have a separate size of `user_id` and `state`. Here is what data looks like.

```
>UserStateR
                 user_id state  meanlat    meanlon countUS countS
                   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>      <dbl>   <int>  <int>
1 ---teJGnwK07UO6_oJfbRw    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1
2 --_ptq_Mp8p9oeCWFT8NJQ    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1
3 --0HEXd4W6bJI8k7E0RxTA    AZ 33.47984 -111.97986       2      1
4 --0KsjlAThNWua2Pr4HStQ    QC 45.50970  -73.58966       6      1
5 --0mI_q_0D1CdU4P_hoImQ    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1
6 --106arHH4D3fLenTl3YZA    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
UserStateR <- read.table(text='
                      user_id             state  meanlat    meanlon countUS countS
                 1 ---teJGnwK07UO6_oJfbRw    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1
                 2 --_ptq_Mp8p9oeCWFT8NJQ    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1
                 3 --0HEXd4W6bJI8k7E0RxTA    AZ 33.47984 -111.97986       2      1
                 4 --0KsjlAThNWua2Pr4HStQ    QC 45.50970  -73.58966       6      1
                 5 --0mI_q_0D1CdU4P_hoImQ    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1
                 6 --106arHH4D3fLenTl3YZA    NV 36.11559 -115.18042       1      1', header=TRUE)
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(UserStateR[,1:2])
V(g)$type <- ifelse(names(V(g)) %in% UserStateR$user_id, 'user', 'state')
V(g)$label <- ifelse(V(g)$type == 'user', '', names(V(g)))
V(g)$size <- ifelse(V(g)$type == 'user', 10, 20)
V(g)$color <- ifelse(V(g)$type == 'user', 'red', 'cyan')
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that really help, have had a hard time on reading igraph manual page :)

Comment: sorry and thank you. This is my first question been XD, oh and here is a further question, I used bipartite layout so I changed the type back to logical after color and size changes. Is there any attribute in igraph that can set attribute directly by column.

Comment: can you give an example what you exactly want to do is not very clear.

Comment: I mean something like V(g)$fromnode.size that can directly set the from node since it is a directed graph. but never mind I think for now I can fix the similar questions on my own.